# Tomcat Landing Page not comming on localhost:8080

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I created a Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse with the name `JavaEEWebContent`. The file structure of the project looks something like this.

[image]

After compiling when I do a "Run on Server", it runs fine.

When I go the link `http://localhost:8080/JavaEEWebContent/`, it works fine and displays me the homepage(in my case its `index.html`).

The problem:
When I go to `http://localhost:8080` it shows

[image]

I know that the landing page for `http://localhost:8080` looks something like this :

[image]

Any idea why it is not coming for me or what could go wrong?

Also I am using `Tomcat 8.5.54`.

This is how my web.xml looks like if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index3.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index2.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index2.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>addNumbers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.addNumbers.AddNumbers</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>addNumbers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/addNumbers</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's wrong. Eclipse is deploying your web application, and only your web application, when it launches Tomcat. What you're expecting to see is a separate web application.  You'll find it in the web-app/ROOT folder of your downloaded copy of Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks!! that makes sense. Could you please elaborate, apologies I am new to this. Like how I make sure eclipse deploys this landing page also. Also I know eclipse by default deploys webapps in  <WORKSPACE LOCATION>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps.

Comment: Create a new series of dynamic web projects, one for each of the default web-apps you want to include. Copy the contents of each web app into one of those project's WebContent folder. Then double-click on the entry in the Servers view for your Tomcat instance and flip the editor that opens over to the Modules page, where you can add each project as a web module map them to the Path / (for ROOT specifically) or to the same names as they were by default. Then they'll be deployed. I'm mentioning it this way because you don't have source projects to draw from, or war files to import from.